# using SerializeJSON from cfm how do I just output the Data portion?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

```
SerializeJSON(cfquery)
```

creates a JSON that looks like this:

```
"COLUMNS":["POINT","LOCATION"],"DATA":[["41.322365,-71.679251","Ashaway...
```

How do I output the JSON Data only?

ie...

```
[["41.322365,-71.679251","Ashaway...
```

Comment: What's your end goal? You can access a query like a struct and pull out data values if that's what you're after

Comment: String functions.   Find the position of the double square brackets and use the right and length functions to get everything afterwards

Comment: I'm trying to push out a JSON/array to support a typeahead.  The typeahead requires a flat JSON/array to push forward.  The typeahead I'm using is: http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/

Comment: @arcee123 - Instead of returning a query object, loop through the query and construct an array of arrays. (That is what the syntax `[]` signifies - an array). Then serialize the array.  Jeremy's answer is close, but the inner element should contain the array of ["POINT","LOCATION"].  See if you can adapt it and let us know if you have problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is a convenient way to do this unless you can modify the code that is serializing the query; otherwise you are going to need to use some string manipulation. However, assuming you have access to the CF code that is serializing the query, this is a little unorthodox but does work:

```
<!---Serialize and Deserialize the cfquery to shortcut obtaining a Structure--->
<cfset queryAsStruct = DeSerializeJSON(SerializeJSON(cfquery))>
<!---Now serialize the data key of the struct--->
<cfset dataJSON = SerializeJSON(queryAsStruct.data)>
```

As I said, not the the prettiest maybe...but seems to get it done. There may be a more convenient/better practice way to convert cfquery to a struct, but this one resulted in fewest lines of code for me.

edit: Just thought to explain why this works. The JSON string when being deserialized by ColdFusion is not detected as a query object anymore, just a plain struct so the "DATA" key is created and populated. THis way you can access it as a key of the structure. When cfquery is a query object, while still a "struct" type of object it has special considerations that prevent you from accessing the data key directly (to my knowledge).

Comment: Points for a creative approach :) However, IMO the proper way to approach it is to generate the correct structure to begin with, rather than mucking with the query object. Create an array of arrays. Then serialize.

Comment: That was perfect Lyndon.  Thank you VERY much.  This made me able to go to build.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Query**

```
q = QueryNew( '' );
point = [ "41.322365,-71.679251" ];
location = [ "Ashaway" ];
QueryAddColumn( q,"point",point );
QueryAddColumn( q,"location",location );
```

**CF10+** *(Using "for row in query" syntax)*

```
data = [];
for( row in q ) {
    // append array of two values
    ArrayAppend( data, [ row.point, row.location ] );
}
data = SerializeJSON( data );
```

**CF9.01**

```
data = [];
for( row=1; row <= q.recordcount; row++ ) {
    rowdata = [];

    ArrayAppend( rowdata,q.point[ row ] );
    ArrayAppend( rowdata,q.location[ row ] );
    ArrayAppend( data,rowdata );
}
data = SerializeJSON( data );
```

**Result:**

```
[["41.322365,-71.679251","Ashaway"]]
```

Comment: This answer brings us to the first line of the question.  It in no way answers it.  Hence the downvote.

Comment: (Edit) The above is close (granted it could use a bit of explanation). Jeremy - It looks like they need to generate an array of arrays.  So the `rowdata` element should be a two element array containing ["POINT","LOCATION"] rather than just a simple string.  Also 1) "Point" the pair of numeric values and "location" is a description like "Ashaway...".  and 2) get rid of the `data = [ data ];` it is not needed and it is not doing what you think it is... Add the descriptions to your sample query and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Perhaps I misread the question, but I thought the required output was as shown in the question's last code example, which is an array containing an array with the data as string pairs? Leigh you may be right, but that's not what I see in the example.

Comment: On rereading the question Leigh I think you're right, my code does output exactly what is illustrated in the question but probaby not what was wanted.

Comment: @JeremyHalliwell - Not quite. Without the closing `[]` it is easy to miss, but if  you look closely, the pair of numbers is a single value. Some sort of city name is the other. So the desired output is more like this: `[ ["41.322365,-71.679251","Ashaway"], ["52.81786,64.12346", "New York"] ]`.

Comment: @Leigh, yes I see it now, I've updated the code to fit that data profile.

Comment: Perfect. Hope you do not mind, but I split the above into two examples to demonstrate the slicker and shorter CF10 syntax you mentioned in the comments. (If you do not like it, feel free to roll it back.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, much better answer now, hope it helps someone in future :-)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same problem, I think.  I'm sending a query to a browser through an ajax call and need to loop through the JSON string in order to display the info.  ColdFusion's serializeJSON method outputs a 1-D array called COLUMNS and a 2-D array called DATA.

Let's assume your JSON string has come back through and ajax call into the "response" variable.  So we have response.COLUMNS and response.DATA.

By using the column name and finding its index, you can pinpoint its data for a given row. From there you do whatever you need.

```
var point;
var location;
for(i=0; i<response.COLUMNS.length; i++){
    point=response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('POINT')];
    location=response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('LOCATION')];
}
```